# check parentId of case and Messaging.InboundEmailHandler class parentid

Tags: email, inboundservices

if case parentid and incoming email parentld same then store the email on its related list

```
 Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailresult();

    List<Case> cs = [SELECT Id, parentId FROM case WHERE parentld =: **** LIMIT 1];
```

what i put at where clause if parentid and incoming email has same parentid should i use Messaging.InboundEmail email or Messaging.InboundEnvelope envelope and how

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the right thing : -

```
// Apex Email Service
    Messaging.InboundEmailResult result = new Messaging.InboundEmailResult();
```

now based on your incoming email you need take the parent id , say if the id is in subject then you can find it in,

```
String strSubject = email.subject;
```

if the id is in body then you can find it in,

```
String myPlainText = email.plainTextBody;
```

from those strings you need to find out the ParentId then you can use it in your own query.